# DownloadManager produces ANR

Tags: android, android-volley, android-download-manager

I am downloading many files (50+) from DownloadManager by enqueue it in a for loop. On start of the download the UI freezes for a while and produces ANR. I am using volley library to access the files from the server and enqueue them in the DownloadManager.

Comment: Try rewriting this as a specific question. Look at this page in the Help section for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm having the same problem. But I only call `DownloadManager.enqueue` once.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get clarity to prevent an ANR error then you could visit [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr.html)

> When the UI thread of an Android app is blocked for too long, an
>   "Application Not Responding" (ANR) error is triggered.

When app needs to do long operations with background thread based like file download the you must handle in [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Once the operation done as you needed in service then you can handle it with the help of [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to make the UI changes based on the background operations.

Note:
If you have good clarity on the android components(**Activity, BroadcastReceiver, and Service**) then you'll not face this kind of issues at your case.